# Sentencias para contar el número de registros por semana, por cada dos semanas, y por mes en MySQL

Tags: mysql

me gustaría saber que sentencias tengo que ejecutar para obtener el conteo del número de registros del mismo tipo (por ejemplo, el número de registros con el mismo "nombre") a lo largo de un día, de una semana, de dos semanas, y de un año.

¿Qué sentencias debo de utilizar? ... Espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

necesitas un

```
"SELECT nombre,COUNT(nombre)as cantidadNombres FROM Usuarios
WHERE fecha >= #"FechaDesde"# AND fecha <= #"FechaHasta"#
GROUP BY ShipperName;
```

explicación,

El `COUNT` cuenta las veces que aparece nombre ( que es el campo por el cual agrupa los datos)
Para usar `between` en la condición tendría que guarda la hora también en la fecha.
De la forma que lo hice si `fechadesde = fechaHasta` entonces filtrará para ese día.

Espero te sirva. suerte